# Input field not removed when populated dynamically through database using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using javascript to add and delete input fields. Fields are properly added, data is saved and displayed too. But when I click remove button in the field that is generated from database, it is not removed. It takes me to the top of the page. But if I click `add more fields`, new field is generated through javascript and it is removed when I click its `remove`. Where am I wrong?

HTML AND JAVASCRIPT

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>

</div>
<?php
// retrieve the user meta
$fb = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'business_sm_fb', false);
if (!empty($fb)) {
    ?>
    <?php foreach ($fb as $f_b) {
        ?>
        <?php foreach ($f_b as $val) { ?>
            <div><input type="text" name="sm_fb[]" type="text" class="regular-text" value="<?php echo $val; ?>" /><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>
        <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
<?php } else {
    ?>
    <div><input type="text" name="sm_fb[]" type="text" class="regular-text" /></div>
<?php } ?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
        var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

        var x = 1; //initlal text box count
        $(add_button).click(function (e) { //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();
            if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
                x++; //text box increment
                $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="sm_fb[]" type="text" class="regular-text" /><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
            }
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) { //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            x--;
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Does the .remove() code gets executed?

Comment: How can I see that using firebug if it gets executed or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue seems to be related to the `wrapper` object:

```
var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap");
```

In your script you bind the click event to all the `.remove_field` items, that are inside the `wrapper` object:

```
$(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) {
    ....
})
```

The problem is that the `.remove_field` items are added via PHP on the **outside** of the `.input_fields_wrap` div, therefore the click event does not work.

As you can see here, the `.input_fields_wrap` is opened and immediately closed after the `<button />`. Your PHP code adds the inputs outside this div.

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
</div>
```

To solve the issue, move the closing div tag after the PHP code block.

Comment: Thankyou @BendErR. It was such a small mistake that made me went nuts. :D